# Detect package launch android

Tags: java, android

I need to detect if an application is launched and I've read that there's nothing in APIs to achieve this.
Someone suggested to give the app the permissions to read logs and keep polling them, but this solution isn't working since JB. 
I also found that since I just need to know if the on top application changes I could do the following:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String str = ((ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo)am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0)).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

But I need to know which way would be the best one to do this continuous polling, and - of course - if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to detect if a *specific* activity is launched, or are you trying to detect *all* activity launches?

Comment: Also, does it matter *how* it was "launched"? There's a difference between launched from the home screen, from recent apps, or just from going back in the stack.

Comment: @Geobits my application needs to monitor all the activity/application launches, and it would be great if I were able to detect if they were launched from home or recent apps.

Answer (score 5):

You could use accessibility service
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html and caputure window change event

Comment: do you have an example on how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As apps are used by people and people need time to read the info on the screen, it is not usual that the foreground app is visible for less than several seconds.

If you are trying to detect what apps the user has launched, then having a background service that polls every second or so polls the list in the way you indicate, then it should work fine and not deplete the battery either as the polling will be stopped as soon as the system goes to sleep.